# AEM Image Upload

Tags: java, aem

On my Website users can Upload Images.
My Problem, it's working just in the internal network.
I get an 403 forbidden because of the csrf token.
But I have implemented the csrf token via standalone config. 

Other Formulars without image upload have no problems with the token, and I can see it in the html, but I can't see the csrf token on image upload form. Do I have to configure the image upload specially?
What could be the problem that I dont get an token just in the upload formular?

I use AEM 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You use Image Upload function on author instance or publish instance ?. If it's a publish instance you should grant right ACL for that.

Comment: it's on publish instance. I already grant the acl to the folder I save the images.